# fs::recursive_directory_iterator exception unhandled

Tags: c++, c++17, std-filesystem

I wrote code that searchs ".data" files in directory, when i do it in this way, works perfectly:

```
std::string path("C:\\Users\\MyPC\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Database");
    std::string ext(".data");
    std::string Datas[50];
    int DataCounter = 0;

    for (auto& p : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(path))
    {
        if (p.path().extension() == ext) {
            Datas[DataCounter] = p.path().stem().string();
            ++DataCounter;
        }
    }
```

but when I input same directory from using std::cin, it throw unhandled exception error. Code like this:

```
std::string path("C:\\Users\\MyPC\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Database");
std::string ext(".data");
std::string Datas[50];
int DataCounter = 0;
SetColor(2);
std::cout << "Please type a path to search database: ";
SetColor(7);
std::cin >> path; //Entered same path. C:\\Users\\MyPC\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Database

for (auto& p : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(path))
{                 //^ exception thrown here
    if (p.path().extension() == ext) {
        Datas[DataCounter] = p.path().stem().string();
        ++DataCounter;
    }
}
```

Error message is this:

> Unhandled exception at 0x764640B2 in Interpol Database.exe: Microsoft
> C++ exception: std::filesystem::filesystem_error at memory location
> 0x00AFE4B8.

Comment: Ok you do not catch exceptions of std::filesystem so those terminate your program when uncaught. Well defined and documented. What is the question?

Comment: You should enter C:\Users\MyPC\OneDrive\Desktop\Database as cin does not resolve escape sequences, was it that?

Comment: Instead of `"C:\\Users\\MyPC\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Database"` you can write `R"(C:\Users\MyPC\OneDrive\Desktop\Database)"`.

Comment: Note that you can have `std::filesystem::path path`, and still use `std::cin >> path`.

Comment: @Evg doesn't work either

Comment: @G.Sliepen you mean, name path already exist in std::filesystem? and I overloaded it?

Comment: @ÖöTiib I entered " C:\Users\MyPC\OneDrive\Desktop\Database ", but still doesn't work

Comment: `std::filesystem::path` already exists, but you did not overload it as far as I can see. This is why namespaces are so nice to have :)

Comment: put both progams in a debugger and see what it says about the contents of `path`.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly; `std::cin.ignore()` Solves the problem.